# PHP: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I'm having trouble with this query. I have 2 date coming from textboxes (don't worry I've taken the necessary sql injection steps). They are used to query a MS SQL Server DATETIME field. I'm getting this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

Here my code:

```
 //formatting my strings
 $from = strtotime($from);
 $to = strtotime($to);

 //this is the where clause in the SQL statement
 "WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate BETWEEN '" . $from ."' AND '" . $to . "') "
```

What am I doing wrong?

Jonesy

Comment: What do `$from` and `$to` contain?

Comment: they are in the date format - dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strtotime converts the data string to a UNIX time stamp
you should use

```
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($from));
$to   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($to));
```

Also bare in mind the 2K38 bug, so if you want to convert dates after 2038 with strtotime() you will get 0

Read more here:[**LINK**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: Nearly there, except that `date()` needs a format string to work

Answer (score 0):

Have u checked that the strings are in the right format to be converted by strtotime? If you go to http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php it has a list of all the accepted formats